# ggplot "glow" effect for line similar to Excel

Tags: r, ggplot2

Does ggplot have a similar line effect as Excel's "Glow"? Based on all my searching I don't think it does, but any other suggestions on how to make one line "stand out" from another line on a plot (other than just alpha)?  My plot is basically 2 time-series of the same xy data, except that one series is the raw 15-min data, the other is the daily average of those data. I would like to bring the daily average data visually to the foreground, and push the 15min data to the background.

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there's no easy way to create the glow (though it's probably possible to hack something if you want it badly enough). Other than varying alpha, how about use different colours? Red (for the foreground line) & grey (for the background line) should provide sufficient contrast & call attention to the former.

Comment: You could also _facet_ the chart. What you want to do can cause serious issues for those with various vision issues. Use annotations if the data doesn't speak for itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How's this?

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = c(1:6), y = c(1,4,3,4,5,2))
ggplot(df) +
  geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y), size = 3, colour = 'red', alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y), size = 2, colour = 'red', alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y), size = 1, colour = 'red', alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: beautiful!, I love a good hack ;).  Being relatively new to R, is this something that can be functionalized or modified to make a custom "glow" setting?